# Android custom toolbar theme not being applied

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I have an app that uses a custom Toolbar style. Previously, it applied the theme correctly, but after a recent update of Android Studio, it has stopped working correctly.

The theme.xml is defined like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="OurTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonAppTheme</item>
        <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/BlueListSeparatorTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_color</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>-->

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btn_accent_color</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="OurTheme" parent="OurTheme.Base">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/BlueListSeparatorTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Our styles.xml contains:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
```

actionbar_text is defined in our colors.xml:

```
<color name="actionbar_text">#ffffffff</color>
```

Finally, our custom toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

Previously, this worked and our app had white text in its custom toolbar. It now defaults to black everywhere in the app and the only method I have found that can change the color of the toolbar title text (other than doing it in code) is to change the toolbar layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyActionBarTitleText"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

Note that now I am specifically telling the actionbar to use MyActionBarTitleText style.

I have also tried to specifically tell it to use the custom theme here as well, by changing the "app:theme" to:

```
app:theme="@style/MyActionBar"
```

but this hasn't helped.

I'm afraid I'm at a loss. I know the base theme works as I can change the background colour, but using the actionBarStyle item simply refuses to work.

This has also affected text layouts and justifications to some of our custom button layouts as well and I can't figure out why it has stopped working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's very late but answering it.

Create a custom theme for your toolbar and set `android:background`

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
       <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item> // change your color here and add other attributes
</style>
```

Now apply this theme to your toolbar in XML like:

```
style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
```